# How to count along the rows based in a value of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe of sessions (aprox 100 columns):

```
    session_init        ID    
0    1                 675    
1    MID               675    
2    MID               675    
3    MID               675    
4    MID               675    
5    MID               675    
6    1                 345    
7    MID               345    
8    MID               345    
9    MID               345    
10   MID               345    
11   MID               345    
12   MID               345    
13   1                 098    
14   MID               098   
15   1                 675    
16   MID               675    
17   MID               675    
18   MID               675    
19   MID               675   
20   MID               675    
21   MID               675    
22   1                 098    
23   MID               098    
24   1                 098    
25   MID               098
```

As you can see in the above pandas dataframe, the seassion start is labeled with `1`. Is there any pandas function that allow me to count the value counts of each session? For example in the above dataframe  the `675` id has started a session 2 times. Thus, the value counts should be:

```
675 : 2
345 : 1
098 : 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be faster to do this simply with `value_counts()`:

```
df.loc[df.session_init == '1', 'ID'].value_counts()

98     3
675    2
345    1
```

Comment: I got: `Series([], Name: ID, dtype: int64)`. Maybe because of the other columns?... here I just put two for this example

Comment: I see the problem.. is not a string is a number

Comment: That's right, the mix of numeric and alphabetical strings will always revert to a column of `object` dtype, which you have  to deal with as you would a string

Answer (score 3):

First filter to only show the '1' values. Then `groupby` the ID column and `count` each of those instances

```
df[df.session_init == "1"].groupby('ID').count()

     session_init
ID               
98              3
345             1
675             2
```

Comment: I got a blank `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

Comment: Try this `df[df.session_init.str.strip() == "1"].groupby('ID').count()`. It solves any problems with `"1"` actually being something like `"1       "`